# Embedding Custom Functions into NN

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, model

I'm currently asking myself how to build a model with a couple of extra functions.
I got an entity of custom functions, and I want to embed them as layers into my model (NN).
For that I'm using TF 2.0. but I'm currently struggling to do that.
All I find is answers about activation functions, but that's not what I'm looking for.

A custom function returns something like a+b or any other algorithm (matrix multiplication etc.)
What we can say is, I have one layer to another one, and want to embed my custom function in between those two layers like so:

[image: input -> dense layer 1 -> custom function 1 -> custom function 2 -> dense layer 2]

I'm going to say that the activation function from one layer to another is the custom function. But what if my custom function takes two inputs? Or I have two functions I want to process my input in before I pass it to the next function?

Another way to solve that problem:
Let's say I got my custom functions `cm*`, and my layers `l*`;
what I do is build a model for each layer I want to put in between two custom functions

```
cm1 -> model(l1) -> cm2 -> model(l2,l3) -> cm3 -> cm4 -> model(l4) -> ....
```

but wouldn't it be stupid to build a model for each of those trajectories?
And what about the loss? The back propagation of residual connected layers is something else than having a lot of models and functions layered together.
Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about TF 2.0, but in Keras you can build your own custom layers that can receive multiple inputs by overriding the Layer class. See https://keras.io/guides/making_new_layers_and_models_via_subclassing/ for more details. The link doesn't explain how to pass in multiple inputs to a layer, but all you have to do is to call the layer with a list of inputs and unpack them inside the call function, something like this:

```
class MyCustomLayer(tf.keras.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        # your code here
        pass

    def call(self, inputs): # example call: MyCustomLayer()([1, 2])
        x, y = inputs
        # your code here
        output = x + y # placeholder
        return output
```

Comment: thx. probably you need to concatenate the input together and process each part/ index of the list seperatly